# Listbox inside the checkbox content - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, checkbox

I have listbox inside the checkbox content. I want the checkbox to be checked whenever any click event happen in the listbox. But the problem it does not check, only clicking on the textblock does check. Any ideas how ?

```
 <CheckBox Checked="orderItemChecked" 
                          Unchecked="orderItemUnchecked" 
                          Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Completed}"
                          HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" >
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=sItemName}" ></TextBlock>
                        <ListBox Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=aSinglOptns}"
                                Margin="20,0,0,0"
                                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SinglOptnTmpl}"
                                Style="{StaticResource SheetListStyle}"
                                ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle}"/>

                    </StackPanel>
                </CheckBox>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try turning the hit testing off from the `ListBox`:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" IsHitTestVisible="false" ... />
```

Answer (score 2):

You can subscribe the event PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp on the CHECKBOX and check it in code behind.